# Weird ruby behavior. Can someone explain it?

Tags: ruby

I was playing with ruby interpreter, then it happened. How?

```
class Expe
  attr_reader :i

  def yo
    @i = 3 
  end
end

a = Expe.new
puts a.yo.i #=> 0+3i
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think what you are doing is converting a.yo into a complex number.
If you put in a `puts a.yo.i.class` it returns `Complex`.

I think what you should be doing is:

```
a = Expe.new
puts a.yo #=> 3 
puts a.i  #=> 3 (returning the 'i' attribute of a)
```

You can see it clearly by just calling the `.i` function on an integer

```
puts 3.i  #=> 0+3i  (convert integer 3 to complex)
```

Answer (score 2):

You call the method `i` on `yo` which is returning a `Numeric`. There is the method `i` defined on `Numeric` that *returns the corresponding imaginary number. Not available for complex numbers.*

see: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-i